# isset not able to determine if property exists

Tags: php, object

I tried to use `isset()` to determine if this property contains something. I run the following checks:

First, I determine if `$property->property_address` contains something:

```
var_dump($property->property_address);
// Outputs
// string(5) "hello"
```

Now if I try it in `isset()`:

```
var_dump(isset($property->property_address));
// Outputs
// bool(false)
```

Why is that? That is why it won'r proceed on my if-else, because isset returns false.

Comment: Wouldn't `!empty()` be the better option for checking that the property contains something?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/c0q-xsn Make sure you are referencing `$property->property_address` rather than `$property->address`.

Comment: Is it an *actual* property of the class, or is it in another data structure using `__set()` and `__get()`, and the class has no `__isset()` method defined?

Comment: I solved this using `empty()`, however I still wonders why `isset()` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing both var_dumps at the same call and check the output

```
var_dump($property->property_address);
var_dump(isset($property->property_address));
```

Comment: he is not doing the dumps at the same call apparently.

Answer (score 0):

This is how you reproduce this exact behaviour:

```
<?php
class Shoop {
    public $actual = 'hello';
    public $mystery = array();

    public function __set($name, $value) {
        $this->mystery[$name] = $value;
    }
    public function __get($name) {
        if(isset($this->mystery[$name])) {
            return $this->mystery[$name];
        } else { return null; }
    }
}

$woop = new Shoop();
echo $woop->actual . "\n";

$woop->fake = 'da' . "\n";
echo $woop->fake;

var_dump(isset($woop->fake));
```

Outputs:

```
hello
da
bool(false)
```

And you address it with:

```
public function __isset($name) {
    return isset($this->mystery[$name]);
}
```

[Documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php)