# Not able to check if property exists in API request object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, http, laravel-api

I am creating a API controller function that will execute only if I will get **test_id** in Request Object otherwise not.I am able to access the Request packet and I am able to see the test_id property in it. I have tried several ways but I am not able make a check for it. This is my controller functions.I have tried using try catch block, It apparently outputs 500 error

*ErrorException: Undefined property: stdClass::$test_id in file C:\xampp\htdocs\backendAPI\app\Http\Controllers\API\TestUploadController.php*.

I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059666/isset-not-able-to-determine-if-property-exists) question and tried both ways(isset() and property_exists()) but didn't helped me. They both returned nothing even I tried echo/die() on both they returned nothing.

```
public function addReadingTestData(Request $req){
        $module = 1;
        $request = $this->getRequestData($req);
        $isTestIdPResent = false;
         try{
             if($request->test_id){
                 $isTestIdPResent = true;
             }
         }
         catch(Exception $e){  
             $this->sendBAdRequestResponse('no test id');
         }
        if($isTestIdPResent){
            foreach($request->question as $ques){
                echo $ques->description."<br>";
                echo $ques->right_answer."<br><br>";
                echo implode($ques->possible_answers,',');
                echo "\n";
            }
        }else{
            return $this->sendBAdRequestResponse('Test Id does not exist.');
        }
    }

public function getRequestData($request){
        return json_decode($request::createFromGlobals()->getContent());
    }

public function sendBAdRequestResponse($errors){
        return response()->json(['error'=>$errors], 400);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use laravel validation to check `$req`.

how you can do this?

find it in this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62589783/9579653